# chromebook： run-as: setegid(aid_package_info) failed: operation not permitted

Tags: android, permissions, chromebook, runas

After I adb connect to a chromebook, and adb shell into chromebook,when i input "run-as com.adobe.reader", i get the following permission related error. Does anyone know how to resolve it or have any idea? Thanks.

James-M-J6YY:7-9 james$ adb shell
atlas_cheets:/ $ run-as com.adobe.reader
run-as: setegid(AID_PACKAGE_INFO) failed: Operation not permitted
1|atlas_cheets:/ $